# SQL - Delete all records as a result of subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm really struggling with an implementation solution here.

```
    SELECT 
      mach_id, 
      value1, 
      CASE 
        WHEN value1 = 0 THEN lead(created_on) OVER (ORDER BY mach_id)
      END, 
      created_on
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE 
      field_name='someValue' and 
      CAST(created_on AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

I need to get the created_on date when the value1 is 0 and then get the lead record created_on date. Then take those dates and Delete all records in another tables where the created_on is between those two dates by mach_id.

I'm really at a loss for a solution here. Any suggestions?

Comment: does your current query return the correct data set of what you want to delete?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  And what do you mean "when the value is 0"?  What `value`?

Comment: Yes the current query returns the data I need to use in the second table for deleting.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Typeo - meant value1.

Comment: what table are you trying to delete from

Comment: just keep going.. add layers.  If you can get the dates, then construct another select to see the records in the other table based on those dates. then when that looks right - add the deelte to the front.

Comment: You are filtering `created_on` to be on the same date as today, careful if you want to display leading dates on posterior dates. You might (or not) want to `PARTITION BY mach_id` in your `OVER` clause. Table data and expected output would be great here.

Comment: @scsimon - Let's say MyOther Table. I need to take the two dates returned from above and use that to delete rows from another table.

Comment: @EzLo - Thanks so much for the comment - that really helped me out! I could have spent a lot of time on that little gem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally came up with the solution, I'm posting it in hopes it'll help someone else. Thanks everyone for the comments and suggestions.

```
    Delete fe from MySecondTable fe join
(Select * from
    (
        Select mach_id, station_id, 
        lag(value1) over (partition by mach_id order by created_on) as shiftEndValue,
        CASE WHEN value1=0 THEN lag(created_on) over (partition by mach_id order by created_on)
            end as shiftEndTime,
            value1, created_on
            FROM MyFirstTable
            where field_name='cur_trgt_cnt' and CAST(created_on AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
    )a
    where shiftEndTime is not null
)b
on fe.mach_id= b.mach_id and fe.station_id=b.station_id 
where fe.created_on between b.shiftEndTime and b.created_on
```